# Logstash split xml into array

Tags: arrays, xml, logstash, logstash-configuration

Is it possible to convert xml into array of objects using logstash?

That'd be my sample document:

```
{
  "Title" : "My blog title",
  "Body" : "My first post ever",
  "Metadata" : "<root><Tags><TagTypeID>1</TagTypeID><TagValue>twitter</TagValue></Tags><Tags><TagTypeID>1</TagTypeID><TagValue>facebook</TagValue></Tags><Tags><TagTypeID>2</TagTypeID><TagValue>usa</TagValue></Tags><Tags><TagTypeID>3</TagTypeID><TagValue>smartphones</TagValue></Tags></root>"
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to output this:

```
{
  "Title" : "My blog title",
  "Body" : "My first post ever",
  "Metadata" : [
    {
      "TagTypeID" : "1",
      "TagValue" : "twitter"
    },
    {
      "TagTypeID" : "1",
      "TagValue" : "facebook"
    },
    {
      "TagTypeID" : "2",
      "TagValue" : "usa"
    },
    {
      "TagTypeID" : "3",
      "TagValue" : "smartphones"
    }
  ]
}
```

However I'm not able to achieve that. I tried using xml filter like that:

```
xml
{
    source => "Metadata"
    target => "Parsed"
}
```

However, it outputs this

```
{
  "Title" : "My blog title",
  "Body" : "My first post ever",
  "@version" : "1",
  "@timestamp" : "2015-10-27T17:21:31.961Z",
  "Parsed" : {
    "Tags" : [
      {
        "TagTypeID" : ["1"],
        "TagValue" : ["twitter"]
      },
      {
        "TagTypeID" : ["1"],
        "TagValue" : ["facebook"]
      },
      {
        "TagTypeID" : ["2"],
        "TagValue" : ["usa"]
      },
      {
        "TagTypeID" : ["3"],
        "TagValue" : ["smartphones"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't want my values to be stored as arrays (I know there's always going to be just one value there).

I know what fields are going to be brought back from my input, so I can map structure myself and this doesn't need to be dynamic (although that would be nice).

[Allow splitting of lists / arrays into multiple events](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2131) seemed to be useful, but it's poorly documented and I couldn't find information how to use this filter for my use-case.

[Logstash, split event from an xml file in multiples documents keeping information from root tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362303/logstash-split-event-from-an-xml-file-in-multiples-documents-keeping-informatio) is similar, but not exactly what I'd like to achieve.

[Logstash: XML to JSON output from array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880172/logstash-xml-to-json-output-from-array-to-string) this seems to be useful, however it hardcodes that first element of array must be outputed as single item (not part of array). It brings me back this:

```
{
  "Title" : "My blog title",
  "Body" : "My first post ever",
  "@version" : "1",
  "@timestamp" : "2015-10-27T17:21:31.961Z",
  "Parsed" : {
    "Tags" : [
      {
        "TagTypeID" : "1",
        "TagValue" : "twitter"
      },
      {
        "TagTypeID" : ["1"],
        "TagValue" : ["facebook"]
      },
      {
        "TagTypeID" : ["2"],
        "TagValue" : ["usa"]
      },
      {
        "TagTypeID" : ["3"],
        "TagValue" : ["smartphones"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

1. Can this be done without having to create custom filters? (I've no
   experience in Ruby)
2. Or am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using logstash's builtin [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html).

**Filter section:**

```
filter {
    xml {
        source => "Metadata"
        target => "Parsed"
    }

    ruby {  code => "
        event['Parsed']['Tags'].each do |x|
            x.each do |key, value|
                x[key] = value[0]
            end
        end"
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"Parsed":{
  "Tags":[
      {
      "TagTypeID":"1",
      "TagValue":"twitter"
      },
      {
      "TagTypeID":"1",
      "TagValue":"facebook"
      },
      {
      "TagTypeID":"2",
      "TagValue":"usa"
      },
      {
      "TagTypeID":"3",
      "TagValue":"smartphones"
      }
  ]
}
```

If I understand you correctly this is your desired result. You need to specify the xml field inside the ruby filter: `event['Parsed']['Tags']`. Does it need to be more dynamic? Let me know if you need anything else.

> Can this be done without having to create custom filters? (I've no experience in Ruby)

Well, yes and no. Yes, because this is not really a custom filter but a built-in solution. No, because I tend to say this can not be done without Ruby. I must admit that Ruby seems to be an unattractive solution. However, this is a flexible approach and 5 lines of code shouldn't hurt that much.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for and is exactly it. I don't mind a couple of Ruby lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most recent Logstash version (5.1.1 at this point) has updated XML filter, which has `force_array` option. It is enabled by default. Setting this to `false` will do exactly the same thing as ruby filter in accepted answer.

Taken from documentation:

> ### `force_contentedit`
>
> - Value type is [boolean](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html#boolean)
> - Default value is `false`
>
> By default the filter will expand attributes differently from content inside of tags. This option allows you to force text content and attributes to always parse to a hash value.
>
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-xml.html#plugins-filters-xml-force_array